# jquery click event is not firing

Tags: jquery

Hi here i want to fire next or prev button click event of jquery full calender.
But the click event is not firing am tried several ways it did not fired

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#contaner_wrapper').css("height", "100%");
    $(".fc-button-prev a span").trigger('click');

    $(".fc-button-next a span").trigger('click');       
    $('.fc-button-prev a span').click(function () {
        alert($("#calendar").fullCalendar('getView').start.toString());

        var abc = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getView').start.toString();

        var ab = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getView').end.toString();
        // Displaymonthevents();
    });

    $('.fc-button-next a span').click(function () {
        // Displaymonthevents();
        alert($("#calendar").fullCalendar('getView').start.toString());
        var abc = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getView').start.toString();

        var ab = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getView').end.toString();
    });

});
```

Comment: are these element dnamically loaded

Comment: Yes, those loading dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be, you are using fullcalendar and these elements are created by fullcalendar plugin, so when this script is executed there is a possibility that the plugin may not have yet created. Which means the event handlers will not get registered.

So the solution is to make use of event delegation

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#contaner_wrapper').css("height", "100%");
    $(document).on('click', '.fc-button-prev a span', function () {
        alert($("#calendar").fullCalendar('getView').start.toString());

        var abc = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getView').start.toString();

        var ab = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getView').end.toString();
        // Displaymonthevents();
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.fc-button-next a span', function () {
        // Displaymonthevents();
        alert($("#calendar").fullCalendar('getView').start.toString());
        var abc = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getView').start.toString();

        var ab = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getView').end.toString();
    });

    $(".fc-button-prev a span").trigger('click');
    $(".fc-button-next a span").trigger('click');       
});
```

Comment: here i want to call web method or page method. $(document).on('click', '.fc-button-prev a span', function () {   PageMethods.EventDetails('E72', onSucess, onError);  });            but its not firing

Comment: what is `PageMethods.EventDetails`?

Comment: PageMethods.EventDetails('E72', onSucess, onError); }); is a pagemethod when this click event is firing.or insted of pagemethod i want to call ajax web method. any one is fine for me                   $.ajax({
                     url: "ViewEvents.aspx/EventDetails",
                     type: "POST",
                     data: "hi",
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     dataType: "json",
                     success: function (data) {
                         alert(data.d);
                     }

                 });

Comment: is it `ASP`? I haven't used it

Comment: yes it is asp.net,but any one is fine for me either ajax web method or page method. please refer this link                http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160947/webmethod-or-pagemethod-returns-error-as-coudnt-get-call-data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you put the code in the same order as your web page, I think you just need to do the trigger after you register the click handler.

Here is a JS Fiddle that does what I think you are asking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/Td5cG/1/

```
$('.fc-button-prev a span').click(function () {
    alert("clicked it");
});

$(".fc-button-prev a span").trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.live()` - old version or `.on()` - new vesion. Example:

`$(".fc-button-prev a span").live('click', function(){
    alert($("#calendar").fullCalendar('getView').start.toString());
})`